# How to create round shape buttons in Qt and set a round shape background image on it? How can we activate pixels of specific part of image in Qt

Tags: qt

i am trying to add a round shape button in my project and i want to set round shape background image on it but the problem is that while setting any background image it is always taking the rectangular image.

Answer (score 0):

You must use bitmap images with transparent background as buttons.

```
    CustomButton::CustomButton(QString file,QString pressedfile,QWidget *parent,int id)
    : QPushButton(parent),FileName(file),PressedName(pressedfile),ID(id)
{
    connect(this,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(slotClicked()));
    setStyleSheet("border: 2px");
```

```
QPixmap pixmap(file)    ;
setMinimumHeight(pixmap.height());
setMinimumWidth(pixmap.width());
setMaximumHeight(pixmap.height());
     setMaximumWidth(pixmap.width());
```

}
void CustomButton::slotClicked()
{
    emit clicked(ID);
}

void CustomButton::setColor(const QColor &c)
{
    fontColor=c;
}

//Paint event of button
void CustomButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *paint)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    p.save();

`p.setPen(Qt::blue);
QPixmap pixmapdown;
if(PressedName>0)
    pixmapdown.load(PressedName);
else
    pixmapdown.load(FileName);
QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap.load(FileName);
if(isDown())
    p.drawPixmap(1,1,pixmapdown);
else
    p.drawPixmap(1,1,pixmap);
if(text().length()>0)
{
    p.setPen(fontColor);
    p.drawText(rect(), Qt::AlignCenter|Qt::AlignHCenter, text());
}
p.restore();
p.end();}`

Comment: I copied just part of my bigger project. It's too much work to extract working part just for you. If you know what you are doing in Qt then this should be enough - you just need to create a header file for it and start using it like any other Widget.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a QStyle derived class, although this might be over the top if you really only want these round buttons and not tons of widgets with custom styling.